# Microsoft Action Pack Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 upgrade questions

Tags: upgrade, windows-8.1, windows-10

Is it possible to upgrade a Windows 8.1 pc to Windows 10 when the Windows 8.1 comes from a Microsoft Action Pack subscription ?

We don't see the little Windows-upgrade-icon in the system tray and don't know if an upgrade is included in the subscription or if we need to do a full new installation.

*(Does the 8.1 to 10 upgrade actually keep all current applications and files or is it a completely new installation?)*

Comment: In the past action pack allowed only the use of the latest O.S. and applications, without event a downgrade right, so if this logic continue (not saying it's the case), not only will it be possible to upgrade to windows 10 but it may be mandatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you should be able to perform a manual update using the new Windows 10 keys which are available in your Microsoft Action Pack Subscription.

Just download the corresponding installation Image and read the key, then the update shouldn't be a problem.

As JFL said in his comment, usually Microsoft's license wants you to upgrade/use (to) the latest OS or program versions anyway.